# $stmt->fetch() not enter in while

Tags: php, mysqli

I have write simple code in PHP, I'm a beginner in this language.

This is my code:

```
$id = "prova";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_item FROM Users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1 ";


if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query))
{
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($result);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   $id_item = (int) $result;
 }

}
```

My problem is that the cycle while is never executed, but I don't understand why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then your query may be returning no results. What do you see for `echo $stmt->num_rows`?

Comment: How do you know that while is never executed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1352288/utkanos yes I have resolved my query returs 0 rows. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense you can use echo :)

Comment: To me, and `id` should be numerical. Are you *sure* there is a record with the `id` as `prova`?